# Thunderbird change default font and size

Tags: email, fonts, thunderbird, size

I love using Thunderbird for checking all my mail accounts, including Gmail and Outlook. However, I'm having a difficult time trying to locate a setting to change the default font and size.  It seems inefficient that I have to change the size of my email and the signature separately each time.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean something else than menu *View > Font Size* ?

Comment: yes. Specifically, the font size for writing the email.

Comment: Try [this advice](https://support.mozilla.org/ml/questions/1387682). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: You can also increase `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` (e.g. to 1.8). It increases the GUI font size but also  font size when writing mails. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Settings** >>> **Composition**
2. Find the section called **HTML Style**
3. You can change the **FONT** and the **SIZE** between *Tiny* and *Huge* (default is *Medium*)